# Use Android XMPP Smack without making public the Service Name and the Host name

Tags: android, amazon-ec2, xmpp, ejabberd

As you see in the example code below, Smack is asking me for a service name and host. I'm using Ejabberd together with Linux and an EC2 instance.

While checking XMPP client apps I have seen the option to create accounts with other XMPP providers. I'm afraid that when I release my app to the public, DNS of my EC2 instance will give people the power to create a crazy amount of accounts and not directly from my app but from anywhere.

Should I use something like Firebase Functions? Or something similar? What's the best way to go around this? I just don't want the hostname to be public.

```
XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration
            .builder();
    config.setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled);
    config.setServiceName(serverAddress);
    config.setHost(serverAddress);
    config.setPort(5222);
    config.setResource(context.getResources().getString(R.string.resource_name));
    config.setDebuggerEnabled(true);
    config.setSendPresence(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementResumptiodDefault(true);
    XMPPTCPConnection.setUseStreamManagementDefault(true);
    mConnection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config.build());
    XMPPConnectionListener connectionListener = new XMPPConnectionListener(type);
    mConnection.addConnectionListener(connectionListener);
```

Comment: You can't prevent discovery of the hostname -- your app accesses it, so it will be extremely trivial to discover.  The hostname is not and cannot be secret, which raises the next question: why, specifically, is that a problem? You seem to have a concern that people would "create a crazy amount of accounts" on your server, so why is that true?  Is your server just sitting there, exposed, (mis?)configured to allow anyone who discovers it to create new accounts, or...?  The threat model is unclear, as is the reason why you mentioned firebase functions... how would using these help?

Comment: Hi bro and thanks for the answer. I have checked Conversations, an xmpp client, it allows you to register accounts with their own xmpp provider or other xmpp providers. I was thinking that maybe somebody takes my hostname, goes to that app and creates an account :/ .Do you think it is possible to make an ec2 instance to respond only to 1 app in specific and nobody else. If that's possible then everything is solved. I was thinking of firebase functions as a solution, like, having there my hostname and do all the logic without anybody seeing my hostname.

Answer (score 0):

This account creation does only work if you did enable the option in your ejabberd config. If you use the standard config provided by ProcessOne and most Linux distributions it should be disabled.
It should something like this:

```
modules:
  # other modules stuff

  mod_register:
    ip_access: trusted_network
```

Where your acl should look similar to this:

```
acl:
  # other irrelevant acls

  loopback:
    ip:
      - "127.0.0.0/8"
      - "::1/128"
```

And the access rule needed should look like this:

```
access_rules:
  trusted_network:
    - allow: loopback
```

This is all according to the documentation of the config, which can be found here: https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/